# Possible to get ESQL using ToTraceString() with parameter values included?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am casting an IQueryable to ObjectQuery and then calling ToTraceString() to get the entity sql:

```
IQueryable<SomeItem> query = context.SomeItem
            .Where(x => x.Timestamp >= start
                     && x.Timestamp <= end);

string eSql = (query as ObjectQuery<SomeItem>).ToTraceString();
```

The 'WHERE' section of the string comes out like so:

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] <= @p__linq__1)]"
```

Is there a way to get the trace string in such a way that the actual DateTime values are already populated into the ESQL rather than these parameter placeholders?

I want to intercept the Entity Sql and use the raw EntityDataReader to iterate the results myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not ESQL but the actual SQL the query was translated to as Linq queries are not translated to ESQL. Parameters are never embedded in the SQL statement to prevent from Sql injection attack. Rather than if there are parameters (for SqlServer) sp_executesql will be invoked since it allows to pass parameters for place holders.